# jQuery UI: Removing class on the change event (nestedSortable plugin)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using Manuele Sarfatti's nestedSortable  (http://mjsarfatti.com/sandbox/nestedSortable/) to create a storable and nested list. I've taken the script one step further by making my list collapsible via additional jQuery (I didn't modify the original plugin script).  I wanted to display open and closed arrow icons to the list items to indicate when they are in their collapsed and expanded state.  I almost have this working except I cannot seem to remove the arrow icon when a parent no longer has children.  To create the arrow icon, I add the class 'ArrowOpen'  to any parent that has children and use the jQuery UI change event to remove all instances of the class and then re-apply the class each time the list is sorted (or changed). For example:

```
$("ul.sortable li:has(ul)").addClass("ArrowOpen");
```

Here is my jsfiddle working example: http://jsfiddle.net/qbxWd/

**To replicate my problem, try this:** Drag/nest  Item-2 into Item-1 and you'll see Item-1 will get the 'ArrowOpen' class and will display an open arrow icon. Now, move Item-2 back to the root level and you'll see that Item-1 continues to retain the 'ArrowOpen' class and the open arrow icon is still present.  If this script worked as intended, when Item-2 was moved back to the root, Item-1 should have lost the arrow icon.

If anyone has any suggestions, any help would be welcomed - thanks!

*Edit:* In full disclosure, I did submit this to the plugin's support forum earlier this week: http://bit.ly/uXbfZY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the stop function add this

```
$("ul.sortable li:has(ul):has(li)").addClass("ArrowOpen");
```

as first line, and delete

```
$("ul.sortable li:has(ul)").addClass("ArrowOpen");
```

from change function

NOTE:

- that it is only a work around and that the arrows will disappear while you drag items, and when you drop them, the arrows appear where it should.
- the "change" function is called several times, if I'm correct, each time you drag it from one item to another without releasing.

I hope this helps!

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/envy/qbxWd/5/

**EDIT**

a even better approach, add the following two lines as first lines in "stop" function

```
            $("ul.sortable li").removeClass("ArrowOpen");  
            $("ul.sortable li:has(ul):has(li)").addClass("ArrowOpen");
```

and remove everything from "change" function, it will make the desired effect and it won't call "removeClass" each time you move an item without releasing it.

**EDIT2**

in case you want it to work with many nested sortables, I suggest this other option which uses a recursive function to apply "ArrowOpen" to all li that has a ul with child li.

[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/envy/qbxWd/7/)

**EDIT3**
You can take this one step further by avoiding having the collapsed nodes lose their class.
Add not('.collapsed') to the add class statement. 
e.g.

$("ul.sortable li:has(ul):has(li) > div > a:not(.ArrowOpen-closed)").addClass('ArrowOpen');

Comment: Dorin - Those are excellent solutions! I think I'll use the code from your first edit. Thank you for your help and including a working example. I've been fiddling with this issue for days, and now I can finally sleep! Cheers!

Comment: I'm glad it helped, next time, be sure to post your code and issue a bit sooner, others are willing to help, good night (: